# Which JQuery dataTable event to use to get the column definition

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am looking at the list of JQuery [DataTable Events](http://datatables.net/reference/event/). I wonder which event I can use to modify the column definition.

Before the data is loaded in the DataTable, I want to hide some of the columns.  Which is the best event to achieve this?

Comment: why use a event cant you use `bVisible` instead under `aoColumns` for columns you looking for .

Comment: @supercool : Can you please tell me how to use `bVisible` ?

Comment: you can check my answer below . hope it helps . cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to hide the columns *before* dataTable initialisation? Seems a little bit odd.  I would use the [**`ColVis`**](http://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) plugin, which provide the abilitiy to show/hide columns without breaking dataTables internal logic. The [**`init`**](http://datatables.net/reference/event/init) event is the right event to attach, since it is triggered only once, after initialisation..

```js
//hide the three first rows after initialisation
$('#example').on('init.dt', function() {
    $('#example').dataTable().fnSetColumnVis([0,1,2], false);
});    

$('#example').DataTable();
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/deyrbctd/**
25x250 click on button demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qLhLpy7s**

Comment: I have tried it and when the grid have 18-20 columns with 250 rows and you run this function, systems takes lot of time to run this function. If I hide the columns before initialization, it takes few seconds and user does not see and lag. I have also passed third param to`fnSetColumnVis`, which is a boolean value which prevents grid redrawing.

Comment: @SharpCoder - dataTables is not a fastrunner, I'll give you that :) Here is an example with 25 columns, 250 rows, where you can hide 3 columns by a click on a button -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qLhLpy7s** do you have significantly slower performance yourself than this fiddle? dataTables is mostly time consuming upon initialisation - after that, the builtin functions / plugins are very well optimised / fast running, imho

Answer (score 0):

using `bVisible` its an alternative approach

```
"aoColumns": [
                  {
                      "sName": "Id",
                      "bVisible": false,
                      "bSearchable": false,
                      "bSortable": false
                  },
                   { "sName": "ContactName" },
                   { "sName": "CompanyName" } ]
```

Comment: I want to do this on click of a button.  I don't want to do this at the deign time. Second question: Assume we can this on click on a button, but how it is differecnt form `fnSetColumnVis` ?

Comment: @SharpCoder, there is actually no difference (as for how the two ways works, as far as I know) - they both just remove the column "physically" from the DOM. The difference is more historically : In 1.10.x, Allan Jardine has rewritten dataTables, and a few parts of the "old" plugin suite is now built into the dataTables core. But not to its full extent, and not so old plugin and new core are compatible.